# Display amount fields in one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data as below

```
V1  01/01/2000  $5,000.00
V1  01/02/2001  $10,000.00
```

Expected result:

```
V1  5000.00/10,000.00
```

I used `listagg` and the output results in:

```
V1 5000/10000
```

The commas and the scale (.00) is lost. How can I achieve to display the amount fields using `listagg` or any other method?

Comment: Are you looking for format functions? `TO_CHAR(field, '$9,999.99')` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
with numbers as
(select 5000 num from dual
union all
select 10000 num from dual)
select listagg(to_char(num, 'fm9G999G999D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'''),'/')
       within group (order by num) "listing"
from numbers;
```